# How to interact with a custom select box with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

When I visit a nike.com store page (test URL listed below) with my Casper script, I'm unable to change the value of the 'skuAndSize' select element. I am verifying this by checking the screenshot that is made after the supposed change. The code I am using to do it is:

```
// Add to cart
casper.then(function() {
  this.fillSelectors('form.add-to-cart-form', {
    'select[name="skuAndSize"]' : '3857923:9'
  }, false);
  this.capture("test.png");
  this.click('button#buyingtools-add-to-cart-button');
});
```

Is there a better way to be handling this?

TEST URL: http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/mercurial-superfly-fg-soccer-cleat/pid-1531739/pgid-1481200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at your link and the select box is hidden. It is replaced with markup which changes the select box under the hood, but the connection between the select box and the custom markup is one way. When you change the select box with JS, the custom markup is not changed.

If you only want to test the add-to-cart functionality, you can just keep it like you have it, because on submit the underlying select box data is used.

If you want to recreate the user interaction then you have to explicitly click this (untested):

```
casper.thenClick(".exp-pdp-size-and-quantity-container > .exp-pdp-size-container")
      .wait(100) // little time to open dropdown
      .thenClick(x("//div[contains(@class,'exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container')]/ul/li[not(contains(@class,'exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock'))][3]"));
```

This should select the third available size by using the CasperJS XPath utility.

Comment: Thank you! Short and to the point. This helps a lot. I was taking screenshots as a way to validate whether or not casper was functioning the way I thought it should be. I am glad to know that that is not a very reliable way to test things!